# How to mutualize appenders properties in log4j.properties file?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a `log4j.properties` file where I have to define ~ 12 different appenders. In fact, all of these appenders are similar, except for the name and the `File` attribute.
I have something like that:

```
log4j.logger.FOO=DEBUG, fileFOO
log4j.appender.fileFOO=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileFOO.File=/some/path/file-FOO.log
log4j.appender.fileFOO.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.fileFOO.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.fileFOO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileFOO.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p ~ %m%n

log4j.logger.BAR=DEBUG, fileBAR
log4j.appender.fileBAR=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileBAR.File=/some/path/file-BAR.log
log4j.appender.fileBAR.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.fileBAR.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.fileBAR.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileBAR.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p ~ %m%n
```

As you can see, all lines are identical except `log4j.logger.X` and `log4j.appender.fileX.File`

Is there a way to define default values for others attributes (`MaxFileSize`, `MaxBackupIndex`, `layout`, etc.) of the appenders, something like an "inheritance" of appender?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement your custom default `Appender` and then use it instead `RollingFileAppender`

```
log4j.logger.FOO=DEBUG, fileFOO
log4j.appender.fileFOO=me.project.MyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileFOO.File=/some/path/file-FOO.log
```

---

```
public class MyRollingFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {

  public MyRollingFileAppender() {
    super();
    init();
  }

  public MyRollingFileAppender(Layout layout, String filename) throws IOException {
    super(layout, filename);
    init();
  }

  public MyRollingFileAppender(Layout layout, String filename, boolean append)
      throws IOException {
    super(layout, filename, append);
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    this.setMaxFileSize("5MB");
    this.setMaxBackupIndex(20);
    this.setLayout( new PatternLayout("%d %-5p ~ %m%n"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that would be my preferred solution. However, I'm using Play Framework v1, and it seems that I can't have my own class loaded by log4j during startup (due to a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/play/+bug/511955) and I don't want to create a JAR library just for that. Thanks anyway :)